# sufficient and necessar condition and surjectivity

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ and $B$ be two matrix from $\mathbb M_n(\mathbb C)$

Give a necessar and sufficient condition on $(A,B)$ such that the linear map : $X\to AX-XB$ from $\mathbb M_n(\mathbb C)$ to $\mathbb M_n(\mathbb C)$is surjective

Comment: The map is surjective if and only if it is injective, by finite dimensionality of $M_n(\mathbb{C})$. Maybe this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** The maps $X\mapsto AX$ and $X\mapsto XB$ commute. Consider their eigenvalues.

**Answer:** Your map is surjective if and only if $A$ and $B$ have no common eigenvalues.

---

**My solution:** Because $X\mapsto AX$ and $X\mapsto XB$ commute, they are simultaneously diagonalizable. Note that the eigenvalues of $X\mapsto AX$ coincide with the eigenvalues of $A$, with possibly a different multiplicity. Similarly, the eigenvalues of $X\mapsto XB$ are the same as those of $B$. Conclude that if $A$ and $B$ have disjoint spectra, their difference can't have $0$ as an eigenvalue

On the other hand: if $u$ and $v$ are eigenvectors associated with the same $\lambda$ for $A$ and $B^T$ respectively, then $uv^T$ is a non-zero element of the kernel.

Comment: did you use the simultaneous diagonalisability?

Comment: or you used a translation to eigenvalues of the matrix $A$ and $B$ ?

Comment: anyway ,by using my method I found that the necessar and sufficient condition : $A$ and $B$ must have nonzero coefficients out of the diagonal and the elements in the diagonal of $A$ and $B$ have to be different .

Comment: @Seginus that's incorrect. For example, take $A=2I$ and $B=I$.

Comment: can you give your solution please

Comment: Are you aware that commuting operators are simultaneously triangularizable? Also, did you try to come up with a proof? Any promising ideas?

Comment: here's my idea : I took tha canonical basis of $M_n(C)$ and I tried to find a sufficient and necessary condition such that  the image of the basis is a basis (which means an independent set )

Comment: I understand your idea you found that the intersection of the spectra of $A$ and $B$ is  emty ?

Comment: I think mine works too :)

Comment: But yours is not equivalent to mine. The example I gave shows that your conditions aren't necessary (but maybe they're sufficient)

Comment: See my latest edit.